# Specifying different DNS servers for different domains

Tags: dns, domain-name

Can I specify DNS servers for multiple domains.
For example there are 3 domains for which I know the DNS server which would resolve the domain name, so can I specify something like

```
b.com (domain)
u1.x1.y1.z1 (DNS server IP address which would resolve b.com)
l.m.n.o (default DNS server used if above DNS server unavailable)

c.com (domain)
u2.x2.y2.z2 (DNS server IP address which would resolve c.com)
l.m.n.o (default DNS server used if above DNS server unavailable)

d.com (domain)
u3.x3.y3.z3 (DNS server IP address which would resolve d.com)
l.m.n.o (default DNS server used if above DNS server unavailable)
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Linux, which distro?

Comment: I want to know if this is possible in Win XP, Vista and 7. For linux RHEL 5.x

Comment: On Linux, including RHEL, you can define multiple nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` - the default behavior is that it will ask the primary nameserver for a name resolution and if doesn't get one it'll go on to ask the rest. In your scenario do the other nameservers have invalid answers or no answers? If it would work to have it check all three and it'll get the right answer then that should work for you.

Comment: I see what your are saying. Basically you are saying I can put domain specific nameservers first and then at the end put the default nameserver. If domain specific nameservers return NO then default nameserver would return the correct answer. I was looking for something where domain specific nameservers would be contacted only if input domain matches with the domain served by those nameservers. For other domains default nameserver should be used without trying domain specific nameservers. Is this possible? I am not very much aware of DNS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

please refer https://github.com/whitekid/dnspost
this provide max osx's resolver functionality.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is appreciated here if answers can stand on their own. So, would you like to add an excerpt of the linked site, so that your answer will still be useful if the link dies?

Comment: Also, constructing complete sentences would be appreciated by many.

Answer (score -3):

Will following help. In /etc/resolv.conf I will specify,

```
search b.com
nameserver u1.x1.y1.z1
search c.com
nameserver u2.x2.y2.z2
search d.com
nameserver u3.x3.y3.z3
```

For d.com, NS u3.x3.y3.z3 will be used (other NS's i.e. u1.x1.y1.z1 and u2.x2.y2.z2 will not be tried for d.com)?
If input domain does not match any of the above given domains then local nameserver will be used?
Also local nameserver will be used if above nameservers are not available or respond with NO?